# Execute bash commands in Java

Tags: java, bash, docker

I have been trying to execute bash commands in Java. I have done it with a couple of ovations, for instance:

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "cd " + folder + "&& find . -type f | grep :*.txt "});
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    return stdInput.lines().count();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

This code works properly, without any errors.

I have tried to use docker with java, in 2 different ways. First way was the "*Runtime.exec()*", as in the previous example:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "cd", "~/IdeaProjects/test/src/main/java/Docker", "&& docker", "build", " -f", "Dockerfile.txt", "-t", "java-app9", "."});
```

The other way was to use the "*ProcessBuilder*", as in the following example:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();

processBuilder.command("sh","cd", "/home/alex/IdeaProjects/test/src/main/java/Docker", "&& docker", "build", " -f", "Dockerfile.txt", "-t", "java-app1", ".");

Process process =processBuilder.start();
```

Both ways do not work without throwing any error.

I have tried also to do it in python:

```
import os


os.system('''cd /home/alex/IdeaProjects/test/src/main/java/Docker && docker build -f Dockerfile.txt -t java-app3 . ''')
```

The python works as it is presented in the following picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z7V6.png)

I expect from this code to run java and create custom containers directly from java. I am using Java 19 and Docker version 20.10.21 .

Comment: Note that in your first working example you pass the entire "script" to bash as a single argument and in the non-working examples you pass multiple parameters after the `-c`: the whole point of the `-c` is to tell bash "treat this as if entered by a user and parse it according to your rules". That means you must give it a single string.

Comment: *Both ways do not work without throwing any error.* Can you show us the error you get?

Comment: Thank you so much @JoachimSauer I did not see that, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke a command in Unix, you provide a sequence of "words".  These are not processed or reinterpreted at all; the first word is the command to invoke and the remaining words are its arguments.  (In a Dockerfile, compare to the JSON-array exec-form syntax of `CMD`.)

In your examples, you're trying to mix this string-array syntax with shell constructs.  If you try to run `"bash", "foo", "&&", "bar"`, then it will specifically use `bash` as an interpreter to run `foo` as a shell script, passing it two arguments `&&` and `bar`.  In your very first example you use `sh -c` passing the rest of the command as a single argument.  This has the right effect, but it makes you vulnerable to a *shell injection attack* if, for example, the `folder` name includes a semicolon.

```java
String folder = "; rm -rf /;";
// uh oh
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash", "-c", "cd " + folder + "&& ..."});
```

All of your commands are of the form `cd directory && command`.  You can use [`ProcessBuilder.directory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)) to set the directory name, and then directly run `command` without actually involving a shell.  This both solves your problem and the security issue.

```java
Process process = new ProcessBuilder()
  .directory(new File("/home/alex/IdeaProjects/test/src/main/java/Docker"))
  .command("docker", "build", " -f", "Dockerfile.txt", "-t", "java-app1", ".")
  .start();
```

The actual right answer to this is to use a [Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) rather than invoke the `docker` CLI tool.  Using [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java), for example, you might write

```java
DockerClientConfig standard = DefaultDockerClientConfig
  .createDefaultConfigBuilder()
  .build();
DockerHttpClient httpClient = new ApacheDockerHttpClient.Builder()
  .dockerHost(config.getDockerHost())
  .sslConfig(config.getSSLConfig())
  .build();
DockerClient dockerClient = DockerClientImpl.getInstance(config, httpClient);

dockerClient.buildImageCmd()
  .withBaseDirectory(new File("/home/alex/IdeaProjects/test/src/main/java/Docker"))
  .withDockerfilePath("Dockerfile.txt")
  .withTags(Set.of("java-app1"))
  .start();
// ...and wait for its completion
```

Remember in any case that, if you can access the Docker socket at all, then you can launch a new container, running as root, bind-mounting the host filesystem, and take over the whole machine.

Answer (score -3):

try to add "/c" at the end of your string, it use to start the command you refer.

Comment: `/c` is an argument to `cmd.exe`, the Windows shell-equivalent. This is about `sh`/`bash`, which is the Unix/Linux shell. Different programs, different arguments.

Comment: even when we talk about cmd.exe, putting it "at the end of your string" does not do anything useful.